# How to Insert a console.log for word under cursor in new line

Tags: key-bindings

**Use case:**

In a JS file, I have an expression like:

```js
if (someVar === 'someValue') {
    statements;
}
```

and, for debugging purposes, I sometimes want to include a `console.log` in the line above:

```js
console.log('someVar:', someVar);
if (someVar === 'someValue') {
    statements;
}
```

**(Working) Attempt:**

I want to have some keybinding to achieve this, so I tried:

```
nnoremap <Leader>L "ayiwOconsole.log(':', );<Esc>2F'"apf "ap
```

that basically yanks word under cursor to register `a`, then writes an empty `console.log(':', );` *template* in the line above, moves to the desired positions and pastes register `a` twice.

It works, but it feels some-way dirty. Can you think of a more elegant way to do the same?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `<C-R>` from insert mode to insert the contents of a register. That way you can insert the whole line at once, including the repeat of the variable name.

For example:

```
nnoremap <Leader>L "ayiwOconsole.log('<C-R>a:', <C-R>a);<Esc>
```

You might want to consider adding a visual mode mapping as well, in which case you can use that also to log the value of an expression, and not just a single variable that will match a word:

```
xnoremap <Leader>L "ayOconsole.log('<C-R>a:', <C-R>a);<Esc>
```

See [`:help i_CTRL-R`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-R) for more details on how `<C-R>` works in insert mode.

Comment: Thanks, filbranden! It definitely looks better than mine!

Answer (score 10):

> Can you guys think of a more elegant way to do the same?

Well, at least we can try our best :-)

```
nnoremap <silent><Leader>L :put! =printf('console.log(''%s:'',  %s);', expand('<cword>'), expand('<cword>'))<CR>
```

Comment: Thank you, Matt! I'll give it a try :)