# Paste word under cursor into new line

Tags: normal-mode

In normal mode I want to be able to select a word and when I press `<leader>i` yield the following string in next line, `The word is <word_that_was_highlighted>`. Is it possible to do this in vim? I attempted a solution using `nnoremap` like as follows but that didn't work.

```
nnoremap <leader>i :let @h=@*<c-r>"hp
```

Here I was attempting to paste the content of register * into h, and then paste that onto a new line.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question, are you looking for something like `nnoremap <leader>i yiwoThe word is <Esc>p` which yanks the current word (`yiw`), adds a new line (`o`) and write `The word is` before going to normal mode and pasting the previously yanked word?

Comment: Yes exactly. Please add this as an answer

Comment: This is pretty much the same as [How to Insert a console.log for word under cursor in new line](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21894/how-to-insert-a-console-log-for-word-under-cursor-in-new-line)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As discussed in the comments you are looking for the following mapping

```
nnoremap <leader>i yiwoThe word is <Esc>p
                   yiw                     Yank the word under the cursor
                      o                    Create a new line under the current one and enter insert mode
                       The word is         Type this string literraly
                                   <Esc>   Switch back to normal mode
                                        p  Past the word you yanked before
```